# Disable leaflet-draw "delete" button

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

How can I disable/remove the delete button in the [leaflet-draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) edit toolbar?
The "edit" button should remain enabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding to the docs in chapter [Disabeling a Toolbar Item](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) you can do the following:

```
    map.addControl(new L.Control.Draw({
        edit: { 
                featureGroup: drawnItems,
                remove: false 
              }
    }));
```

This adds a new Control bar without the *delete* Button, but the *edit* button will remain

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditControl
  position="topright"
  edit={{
    remove: false,
    edit: false
  }}
/>
```

Comment: if you want the edit button active, you can remove the edit:false part