# How to remove save option from leaflet draw api delete button?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

My question is similar to [leaflet-draw delete button remove "clear all" action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46934768/leaflet-draw-delete-button-remove-clear-all-action) but I want to remove save option instead of clear all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are no customization provided by draw api to do that. So I have added a custom css to hide it.

Apart from that, we can also customized the plugin as follows :
To change the text :
*`L.drawLocal.edit.toolbar.actions.clearAll.text = t('Clear');`*

To overwrite the clear method :

```
L.EditToolbar.Delete.prototype._enableLayerDelete = function(t) {
                me.drawToolbar = this;
                (t.layer || t.target || t).on("click", me.clearAllCustom, this)
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the actions of the EditToolbar via L.EditToolbar.include function and return the actions while not including the save option:

```
L.EditToolbar.include({
  getActions: function (handler) {
    var actions = [
      {
        title: L.drawLocal.edit.toolbar.actions.cancel.title,
        text: L.drawLocal.edit.toolbar.actions.cancel.text,
        callback: this.disable,
        context: this
      }
    ];

    if (handler.removeAllLayers) {
      actions.push({
        title: L.drawLocal.edit.toolbar.actions.clearAll.title,
        text: L.drawLocal.edit.toolbar.actions.clearAll.text,
        callback: this._clearAllLayers,
        context: this
      });
    }

    return actions;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The additional CSS was a good solution for me. I add the code, as it was not provided in the previous answer:

```
ul.leaflet-draw-actions.leaflet-draw-actions-bottom li a[title="Save changes"],
ul.leaflet-draw-actions.leaflet-draw-actions-bottom li a[title="Cancel editing, discards all changes"] {
    display: none;
}
```