# How to remove save option from leaflet plugin in angular?

Tags: angular, leaflet

I have tried the possibilities by referring [How to remove save option from leaflet draw api delete button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360283/how-to-remove-save-option-from-leaflet-draw-api-delete-button?answertab=oldest#tab-top),but save option is not deleted from the page.
Please suggest me what to do here.
Please check the code I have given.

`

```
drawPluginOptions = { 
   draw: {
    polygon: {
    allowIntersection: false,
    repeatMode: false,        
    shapeOptions: {
      color: '#305496',
      fill: null,
      fillColor: null,
      fillOpacity: 0.2,
      opacity: 1,
    }
  },
  polyline: false,
  circle: false,
  rectangle: {
    showArea: false,
    repeatMode: false,
    shapeOptions: {
      clickable: false,
      color: "#305576",
      fill: null,
      fillColor: null,
      fillOpacity: 0.4,
      opacity: 1,
      stroke: true,
      weight: 2,
    }
  },
  marker: false,
  circlemarker: false
},
edit: {
  featureGroup: this.editLayers,
  edit: false,
  remove: true
}
```

};`

Answer (score 0):

`::ng-deep .leaflet-draw-actions li:first-child a { display: none; }`

This gives me solution