# Disabling leaflet-draw “edit” button and customizing "delete" button options

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I know there's a [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40414970/disable-leaflet-draw-delete-button) for disabling just the “delete” button in [`leaflet-draw`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw)'s edit toolbar.

I'm wondering if there is a complementary setting, i.e.: disabling the *edit* button but keeping active the *delete* button (the one with the trash bin icon).

Besides, I'd like to know if there is an easy way for customizing the "delete" button options. I need to disable the "Save" options that you see once you have clicked on the delete icon.

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/40419084/4768502 but replacing `remove` with `edit`? See also https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/6bc037bc0c160ac9338bc7e62153dbe33fea6fa3/src/Leaflet.draw.js#L169

Comment: @IvanSanchez excuse me if I take advantage of this post, I updated my question a little bit. :)

Answer (score 5):

**Are you looking for this ?**

```
edit: {
      featureGroup: drawnItem,
      edit: false
    }
```

**CSS**

```
.leaflet-draw-actions {
  display: none !important;
}
```

**Or this ?**

```
L.Draw.Toolbar.include({
    save: false,
    cancel: false
});

new L.Control.Draw({
    edit: {
        edit: false,
        featureGroup: drawnItems
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: I wanted to have only delete option on Edit Toolbar and this solved my scenario.

edit: {
      featureGroup: drawnItem,
      edit: false
    }